# Spring QuerydslPredicate's naming convention to snake case

Tags: spring-data, naming-conventions, querydsl, predicate, spring-data-commons

I'm using Predicate from QueryDsl. Backends internally uses camelCase, but promised to use snake_case when communicating with clients.

I want to use `snake_case` as query parameters like

```
http://localhost:8080/inputmethod?protocol_type=SDK
```

if I pass `protocol_type` as snake_case, Query Dsl Predicate doesn't parse it. It parse only fields of the type(target entity class) as camelCase. so `protocol_type` is skipped by getPredicate() of `QuerydslPredicateBuilder`.

```
    /**
     * Creates a Querydsl {@link Predicate} for the given values, {@link QuerydslBindings} on the given
     * {@link TypeInformation}.
     *
     * @param type the type to create a predicate for.
     * @param values the values to bind.
     * @param bindings the {@link QuerydslBindings} for the predicate.
     * @return
     */
    @Nullable
    public Predicate getPredicate(TypeInformation<?> type, MultiValueMap<String, String> values,
            QuerydslBindings bindings) {
    ...
            if (!bindings.isPathAvailable(path, type)) { // <-- here!
            // path : "protocol_type"
            // type : my.domain.entity.InputMethod
                continue;
            }
   ...
}
```

but it works in `cameCase`.

```
http://localhost:8080/inputmethod?protocolType=SDK
```

How to set the naming convention of Predicate to `snake_case`?

---

#### Controller

```
    @GetMapping
    public List<InputMethodDto.Response> getInputMethodTypeList(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = InputMethod.class) Predicate predicate) {
        return service.getInputMethodList(predicate);
    }
```

#### Entity

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class InputMethod {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private RecordType recordType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private ProtocolType protocolType;

    @Column
    private String name;
```

#### Config

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
}
```

---

**Jackson naming strategy**
Same issue with me.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273966/spring-jpa-querydslpredicate-snake-case

I also set `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am afraid you can't use snake_case here, simply because `_` is considered as property splitter in spring data mapping. So mapper will convert it to `protocol` and `type`

Comment: thank you for answering. I found another way using `bindings.bind(path).as(alias)`. I can alias each camelCase path to snake_Case path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949660/how-to-sort-by-querydsl-alias